# Indexing on axis by list in PyTorch

Tags: indexing, pytorch

I have Variables lengths_X of size (10L,) and A of size (10L, 16L, 5L).

I want to use lengths_X to index along the second axis of A. In other words, I want to get a new tensor predicted_Y of size (10L, 5L) that indexes axis 1 at i for all entries with index i in axis 0.

What is the best way to do this in PyTorch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is actually called `batched_index_select` and I looked for such functionality before but couldn't find any native function in PyTorch that can do the job. But we can simply use:

```
A = torch.randn(10, 16, 5)
index = torch.from_numpy(numpy.random.randint(0, 16, size=10))
B = torch.stack([a[i] for a, i in zip(A, index)])
```

You can see the discussion [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/batched-index-select/9115). You can also check out the function [batched_index_select](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/master/allennlp/nn/util.py#L675) provided in the [AllenNLP](https://allenai.github.io/allennlp-docs/index.html) library. I would be happy to know if there is a better solution.